# Multiple RewriteCond doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, rewritecond

I have in htaccess some like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bar
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^some
RewriteRule ^register,(.*)$ /register.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^offer,(.*)$ /offer.html [R=301,L]
```

It redirect me if I write http://foo.domain.com/register,one.html I want it only on http://domain.com/register,one.html or http://www.domain.com/register,one.html

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example that you've given, you will most certainly not be redirected.

However, it looks like you're expecting the `RewriteCond` directives to apply to both of the `RewriteRule` directives - they do not.  They only apply to the `RewriteRule` that immediately follows them.

So, in your example, `http://foo.domain.com/register,one.html` will **not** redirect you - but `http://foo.domain.com/offer,one.html` will.

What you probably need is something more along these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(foo|bar|some)
RewriteRule ^register,(.*)$ /register.html [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(foo|bar|some)
RewriteRule ^offer,(.*)$ /offer.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Consecutive `RewriteCond` directives have an implicit *AND* between them and since yours are mutually exclusive, the `RewriteRule` would never be reached.  Shane's example deals with that problem too.  You can also place `[OR]` after a `RewriteCond`.

Comment: @Ladadadada Actually, it's functionally equivalent, I was just going for extra efficiency and ease of reading.  He's got `!` preceding those condition match strings, so they're all negative matches - "(not A) and (not B) and (not C)", while mine is "not (A or B or C)".